# XML Export from SAS

Tags: xml, sas

I am creating a mapping document (using XPaths) to export a SAS dataset to an XML format.

I am wanting to create a nest within a nest and am using the following code:

```
<COLUMN name="var1">
<PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/KINGDOM/ANIMAL/SPECIES/var1</PATH>
 <TYPE>character</TYPE>
 <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
 <LENGTH>5</LENGTH>
 </COLUMN>

 <COLUMN name="var2">
 <PATH syntax="XPath">/REQUEST/KINGDOM/FLORA/TYPE/var2</PATH>
 <TYPE>character</TYPE>
 <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
 <LENGTH>13</LENGTH>
 </COLUMN>
```

The resulting XML spits out the below:

```
<ANIMAL>
<SPECIES>
<var1>XXX</var1>
</ANIMAL>
<FLORA>
<TYPE>
<var2>YYY</var2>
</SPECIES>
</TYPE>
</FLORA>
```

The species end tag is in the wrong place.

The SAS code I am using to export the dataset to a XML is this:

```
filename SGFXML1 "D:\test1.xml";
filename map "F:\Desktop\mymapout.map";
libname SGFXML1 xml92 xmltype=xmlmap xmlmap=map;

data sgfxml1.test;
 set test;
run;
```

How do I go about fixing this? I think the problem comes as I am creating a nest within a nest but not sure.

Comment: Add the SAS code you wrote, and also paste in any important messages from the LOG window you see

Comment: Hi Richard, The SAS code to export is above....as I am just testing this, the log contains a lot of 'Output column XXX does not occur in XMLMap definition of table test'